# OLED on Zedboard

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, xilinx, spi, zynq

I am very new to zedboard. I have a zedboard running an Ubuntu image. I am trying to write a driver to run the OLED on the board. On board start-up the OLED on the board shows some display(Xilinx logo), therefore I am assuming it already has a driver. I have the following questions:

a) How is the OLED in the zedboard internally connected, is it through SPI, GPIOs or the PL. If it's through SPI/GPIOs then which pins?

b) Any tutorial or documentation that I can follow to create userspace drivers using SPI/GPIO for the OLED in the zedboard?

c) I have a redhat desktop, is there any SDk I can use to develop userspace drivers for the zedboard from my redhat desktop.

I have seen a lot of materials on the zedboard but none of them talks about how the OLED is internally connected. In one document it shows that it's connected to the PL. If that's the case then how can I write userspace drivers using the PL on the zedboard? I will be coding using C.

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a) How is the OLED in the zedboard internally connected, is it through SPI, GPIOs or the PL. If it's through SPI/GPIOs then which pins?

First or second result for the *web* search "zedboard oled pdf" - http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/ZedBoard_HW_UG_v1_1.pdf
then search for "oled" in it (page numbers of the pdf file, not printed in document):

> page3: 2.4.4 OLED...... ... ...... 19
>
> page4: 128x32 OLED Display
>
> page5: ZYNQ XC7Z020-CSG484 OLED <- bus_of_5 -> 128x32 OLED
>
> page20: 2.4.4 OLED
>   An Inteltronic/Wisechip UG-2832HSWEG04 OLED Display is used on the ZedBoard. This
>   provides a 128x32 pixel, passive-matrix, monochrome display. The display size is 30mm x11.5mm x 1.45mm. Table 11 - OLED Connections ... Interface

```
oled_pin symb  EPP_pin  Function
9        RES#   U9      Power Reset for Controller and Driver
8        CS#    N/C     Chip Select – Pulled Down on Board
10       D/C#  U10      Data/Command Control
11       SCLK  AB12     Serial Clock Input Signal
12       SDIN  AA12     Serial Data Input Signal
```

So, we know model of OLED `UG-2832HSWEG04` (datasheet http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/UG-2832HSWEG04.pdf with low-level details on data interface) and data connection; this is OLED with 1 serial data input and 1 serial clock.

Pinout pdf is http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug865-Zynq-7000-Pkg-Pinout.pdf (too long to read), but there is shorter version of pin list in txt format: http://www.xilinx.com/support/packagefiles/z7packages/xc7z020clg484pkg.txt

Device/Package xc7z020clg484 9/18/2012 10:07:35

```
Pin   Pin Name                 Memory Byte Group  Bank  VCCAUX Group  Super Logic Region  I/O Type 
AA12  IO_L7P_T1_13             1                  13    NA            NA                  HR        
AB12  IO_L7N_T1_13             1                  13    NA            NA                  HR
```

HR means "3.3V-capable high-range (HR) banks", both data pins are from "bank 13". Pin name is IO_* so it "supports both input, as well as output functionality", and is part of "PL Pins" (PL = programmable logic = FPGA). Default Zedboard firmware of FPGA part gives access to this pin to the ARM part of chip with linux kernel (PS = processing system = ARM) by routing it to some internal processing_system GPIO pin via system.ucf file like:

```
NET processing_system7_0_GPIO_pin[5]  LOC = AB12 | IOSTANDARD="LVCMOS25";  # "OLED-SCLK"
NET processing_system7_0_GPIO_pin[6]  LOC = AA12 | IOSTANDARD="LVCMOS25";  # "OLED-SDIN"
```

Then the GPIO pins are registered in devicetree (dts) https://github.com/Digilent/linux-digilent/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/digilent-zed.dts in `zed_oled` group:

```
zed_oled {
        compatible = "dglnt,pmodoled-gpio";
        /* GPIO Pins */
        vbat-gpio = <&ps7_gpio_0 55 0>;
        vdd-gpio = <&ps7_gpio_0 56 0>;
        res-gpio = <&ps7_gpio_0 57 0>;
        dc-gpio = <&ps7_gpio_0 58 0>;
        /* SPI-GPIOs */
        spi-bus-num = <2>;
        spi-speed-hz = <4000000>;
        spi-sclk-gpio = <&ps7_gpio_0 59 0>;
        spi-sdin-gpio = <&ps7_gpio_0 60 0>;
    };
```

> b) Any tutorial or documentation that I can follow to create userspace drivers using SPI/GPIO for the OLED in the zedboard?

According to Avnet's Getting Started pdf, "Demo 2 – OLED Display" scetion on page 17 (web searched as "zedboard oled") http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/GS-AES-Z7EV-7Z020-G-14.1-V6%5B1%5D.pdf#page=17 there is kernel driver `pmodoled-gpio.ko` (on screenshot it reported as "pmodoled-gpio-spi"), so OLED is driven with GPIO pins.

There are two helper scripts: `unload_oled` to remove the kernel module and `load_oled` to insert it into kernel. Driver will create special device file `/dev/zed_oled` to work with display from user-space and `load_oled` also displays the `/root/logo.bin` file using this `zed_oled` interface.

Typical usage of `zed_oled` is like `cat yourfile.bin > /dev/zed_oled`, for example http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/~lin.zhang/notes/emebedded-linux/zedboard-oled-display.html  and better http://zedboard.org/content/zedboard-oled

> The .bin file format.  ... The screen is written to right to left, top to bottom with each pixel being represented by a bit within one of the bytes within the .bin file.  Bits are read-in top down 8 pixels then move over 1 pixel and write the next 8 bits and continue until you are at the end of the row.  Then move down 8 pixels and do this again 3 more times.

You can do writes from C application, check code from http://www.cnblogs.com/popo0904/p/3853144.html (you can use online *web* translation services to read the text)

Documentation on the kernel module `PmodOLED` used in standard zedboard demo: https://github.com/Digilent/linux-digilent/blob/master/Documentation/pmods/pmodoled.txt

> The driver provides a 512 Byte display buffer for the display of PmodOLED.
>   The Whole screen is divided into four lines, each of them is 128 bits wide
>   and 8 bits high, as shown in the figure below.

```
    +--------------------------...----------------------------+
    +                         Line 4                          +
    +--------------------------...----------------------------+
    +                         Line 3                          +
    +--------------------------...----------------------------+
    +                         Line 2                          +
    +--------------------------...----------------------------+ MSB (bit 7)
    +                         Line 1                          +
    +--------------------------...----------------------------+ LSB (bit 0)
byte 127                                                     byte 0
```

> Users can perform read and write functions to the device node to access the data
>   inside the display buffer.

And there is source code of the dirver: https://github.com/Digilent/linux-digilent/blob/06b388903e5459687ba2538ae3895ffe29e2e39e/drivers/pmods/pmodoled-gpio.c

> c) I have a redhat desktop, is there any SDk I can use to develop userspace drivers for the zedboard from my redhat desktop.

The standard driver is kernel-space for this OLED on ZEDboard, you can use it from precompiled ZEDboard firmware. Or you can build the kernel according to zedboard instructions, all in-kernel drivers will be built too (if enabled in kernel configuration): http://zedboard.org/content/creating-linux-kernel-image-boot-zc702-sd-card-slot

Comment: Does fbtft driver cover this type of displays? I think so and I think there is no need to create a custom driver per each strange device :-)

Comment: Andy, the UG-2832HSWEG04 is not listed as supported by fbtft https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules. And fbtft is newer than pmodoled (2012)